# Traffic light light system with sensors

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to make a traffic light system with a ultrasonic range sensor as well as a light dependant resistor. I'm trying to make it so that the default setting is 2 seconds red light 1 second yellow 2 seconds green then 1 second yellow, this will then repeat until something else happens - I've got this working fine.

Then I want 2 different states.

One where if something comes with 10cm of the sensor then the buzzer will beep and the yellow light must blink on and off 10x with intervals of 0.1ms. When the object moves away it must then return to the default setting.

Secondly I want it when the LDR detects that the light has dropped below a level the red light will turn on and stay on until a object approaches the sensor. When an object is near the sensor it must then turn the red light off and turn the Green light on.

Here is all the code i have so far and i cant figure out why its not working.
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

```
    #define ECHOPIN 3
    #define TRIGPIN 2
    float distance;
    long distancecm;


    int RED = 13; 
    int YELLOW = 12;
    int GREEN = 11;

    int piezoPin = 8;

    int sensorpin = A0;
    int sensorvalue = 0;


    void setup() {
      pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(YELLOW, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(ECHOPIN, INPUT);
      pinMode(TRIGPIN, OUTPUT);
      }


    void distancesensor()
      {
      digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(2);
      digitalWrite(TRIGPIN,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(10);
      digitalWrite(TRIGPIN,LOW);
      distance = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH); 
      distancecm = distance/29.1/2;
      if (distancecm <=10);
        for (int j=1; j<=5; j=j+1)
        {
         tone(piezoPin, 1, 500);
         digitalWrite(YELLOW, HIGH);
         delay(100);
         break;
         }
    }


    void lightsensor()
      {
      sensorvalue = analogRead(sensorpin);
      if (sensorvalue > 500)
        digitalWrite(RED,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(2);
        digitalWrite(TRIGPIN,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        digitalWrite(TRIGPIN,LOW);
        distance = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH);
        distance = distance/58;
        while (distance >10)
          digitalWrite(RED,LOW);
          digitalWrite(GREEN,HIGH);
          digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);
          delayMicroseconds(2);
          digitalWrite(TRIGPIN,HIGH);
          delayMicroseconds(10);
          digitalWrite(TRIGPIN,LOW);
          distance = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH);
          distance = distance/58;


       }




    void loop() {
      distancesensor;
      lightsensor;
      digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);          //RED ON
      delay(2000);                      //WAIT 2 SECONDS
      digitalWrite(RED, LOW);           //RED OFF  
      delay(200);
      distancesensor;
      lightsensor;
      digitalWrite(YELLOW, HIGH);       //YELLOW ON
      delay(1000);                      //WAIT 1 SECOND
      digitalWrite(YELLOW, LOW);        //YELLOW OFF
      delay(200);
      distancesensor;
      lightsensor;
      digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);        //GREEN ON  
      delay(2000);                      //WAIT 2 SECONDS
      digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);         //GREEN OFF
      delay(200); 
      distancesensor;
      lightsensor;
      digitalWrite(YELLOW, HIGH);       //YELLOW ON
      delay(1000);                      //WAIT 1 SECOND
      digitalWrite(YELLOW, LOW);        //YELLOW OFF
      delay(200);
      distancesensor;
      lightsensor;
      //REPEAT
      }
```

[image]

Comment: How is it not working? Describe the problem further? Is it not reacting on your sensors? Do you get a compile error?

Comment: Try not to use delay for other things than really simple test code. Instead use non-blocking code like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example of the Arduino IDE. And this kind of project I would program it as a state machine, which also would make things simpler when using non-blocking code

Comment: this exact question has been asked before, and i think that it was a different OP,  which tells me that this may be a school assignment. .... is it a school assignment? .... did you write the code?

Comment: STATE ALGORITHMS! You need state algorithms!

Comment: Chrisl, The problem is that the sensors don't seem to be reacting to anything. i don't get any compile errors.

Comment: jsotola ill have a look then. thanks, its a uni project and yes i wrote all the code myself.

Comment: Kingduken i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: It is likely, that the circuit doesn't seem to react, because the code is busy waiting in the delay function. You have up to 2,8 s delay between the measurements. Show us your schematic/wiring, so that we can check that the delays are really the problem

Comment: Chrisl ive updated the post with the picture of what the wiring looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The photo of your circuit doesn't really show, how all the components are wired. For this you should either draw a schematic (which you can do with the schematic tool directly in the question editor) or provide a good visible wiring diagram like from Fritzing (though a proper schematic would be better).

For now I cannot see any wrong wiring, though you definitely should recheck it and add a proper diagram to your question.

For your code I will shortly sketch the functionality of non-blocking code and a state machine:

1. **Non-blocking code:** Task, that require a long amount of time (this means long for a microcontoller; seconds are long in this context), you should not use code, which blocks the whole program execution, until the task is completed. Instead you should only shortly check, if there is an action to be taken. If not, quickly proceed with other code. This enables you to do, which seems to be multitasking. For timed sequences you can use the `millis()` function. It returns the number of milliseconds since the program has started and overflows after 50 days. The following code saves the timestamp, when the LED was toggled the last time and checks, if enough milliseconds have passed since the last time. This way you can do something else in the meantime (like checking the state of your sensors). Also refer to the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example of the Arduino IDE.

```c
unsigned long timestamp = 0;
unsigned long interval = 500;
...
void loop(){
  if(millis() - timestamp > interval){
    digitalWrite(led_pin, !digitalRead(led_pin));
    timestamp = millis();
  }
}
```

2. **State machine:** A state machine is code, that holds it's current state in a variable, thats mostly numeric. This variable is read at every loop cycle and used to determine, which piece of code is to be executed. In your case you would have states for "red light on", "yellow light on", "green light on", "distance lower than 10cm" and "LDR reports low light condition". Each on this gets it's own number. For convenience you should use an enum. Now on every loop cycle we use a switch case to go to the right code depending on the state. For your case you would set the state code with non-blocking behavior as described above. Then you only need transitions between the states, by setting the state variable.

```c
enum STATE {STATE1, STATE2, STATE3};
STATE state = STATE1;
...
void loop(){
  switch(state){
    case STATE1:
      digitalWrite(led1_pin, HIGH);
      if(millis() - timestamp > interval){
        digitalWrite(led1_pin, LOW);
        state = STATE2;
      }
      break;
    case STATE2:
      // doing whatever this state needs to do and then do transition with setting state variable
      break;
    case STATE3:
      // doing whatever this state needs to do and then do transition with setting state variable
  }
}
```

For designing the states and transitions it sometimes makes sense to sketch them on paper. A bubble with a names is a state and then you connect these states with arrows.

Since you want to check the sensors in every state, you should do this outside of the `switch` statement. The measurement functions then do nothing else but the measurement and setting the `state` variable accordingly (so no `digitalWrite()` or `delay()` in there).